# Graph from matrix GraphX

Tags: scala, apache-spark, graph, spark-graphx

I have matrix in csv file that looks like this:

```
   A  B  C  D
A  0  3  2  5
B -1  0  2  9
C -1 -1  0  8
D -1 -1 -1  0
```

I want to create graph in Spark using GraphX. I have vertices from another file and now I am trying to create edges with values from the matrix. But I am stuck here.

```
val Vertices: RDD[(VertexId, String)] = data.map(_.split(",")).map { arr =>
      val id = arr(0)
      val place = arr(1)
      (id.toLong, place)
}

val edges: RDD[Edge[Double]] = edgesData.map(_.split(",")).map { arr =>
      val place1 = arr(0).toLong
      val place2 =
}
```

How can I create edges from matrix from csv file?

Comment: Have you found a satisfactory answer?

Answer (score 0):

GraphX requires you to provide a `VertexId` which is a unique `Long` identifier for each vertex. Only using the RDD API, that requires a little bit of gymnastic but here is a way to do it.

I don't have the exact structure of your csv file, here is what I used:

```
> cat matrix.csv 
,A,B,C,D
A,0,3,2,5
B,-1,0,2,9
C,-1,-1,0,8
D,-1,-1,-1,0
```

In what follows, I stressed the code lines that you should adapt may your file be slightly different.

```scala
val data: RDD[(VertexId, String)] = sc.textFile("matrix.csv")
// getting the list of vertex names based on the CSV header
// adapt this line to your file structure
val vertex_names = data.first.split(",").tail

val vertices : RDD[ = data
    // removing the header, adapt this line to your file structure
    .filter(! _.startsWith(","))
    .zipWithIndex
    .map{ case (arr, id) => id -> arr.split(",")(0) }.cache()

val vert_index: RDD[(String, VertexId)] = vertices.map(_.swap)

// and now the gymnastic, we create a RDD of edges and then join with vert_index
// to replace vertex names by their VertexId 
val edges: RDD[Edge[Double]] = data
    .filter(! _.startsWith(","))
    .map(_.split(","))
    .map(arr => arr.head -> arr.tail.map(_.toDouble))
    .map{ case (letter, weights) => letter -> header.zip(weights) }
    .flatMapValues(x=>x) // this line generates one row per edge
    .join(vert_index).map{ case (_, ((out, weight), in)) => out -> (weight, in) }
    .join(vert_index).map{ case (_, ((weight, in), out)) => Edge(in, out, weight) }
```